# launch activity in library module from main module

Tags: android

I have 2 different modules, module A and module B is library module. In module A, there is a button that will launch activity library module B when user click the button. How do i link the button to launch activity in module B?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply...i will definitely try this and update the result to you later .

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the package name in the Intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourClassA.this, com.your.package.name.ClassB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two scenarios I see here:

## Scenario #1:

Module A includes module B in its build.gradle file.  If so, module A can directly start the Activity because the Activity is visible to it.  This would be (in Kotlin):

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, ActivityInModuleB::class.java)
    // Possibly add extras here
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

## Scenario #2:

Module A does NOT include module B, but both are in the same project.  In this case, the `ActivityInModuleB` class would not be visible to module A, so you could not import it and use it directly.  In this case, there's a few possible solutions...

### Option #1:

Use `<activity-alias>` in your AndroidManifest.xml for module B to associate `ActivityInModuleB` to a string.  Then you can create the Intent in module A and call `intent.setAction(actionStringInManifestGoesHere)` and thus you can indirectly refer to this class.

I personally haven't used this approach, though I wanted to in a previous project.  It's just that that project was already using option #2 and it would have taken a while to switch over.

### Option #2:

Setup a LocalBroadcastReceiver in a module that includes both module A and module B.  Then, each module can register themselves as handling broadcasts.  When a broadcast is sent, an action is attached (similar to option #1).  The broadcast receiver will call each module's handler and give it an opportunity to start the appropriate Activity, if it finds the associated action in its supported list.  At the point a module starts an Activity it can return true to say it handled the action and your main module can decide to either short circuit calling any other modules' handlers OR let all modules have an opportunity.

This approach definitely works (it's used in an app with millions of installs).  BUT, I think it's basically just recreating option #1, so probably is overkill.